# For loop not iterating for each input C# - beginner question

Tags: c#, for-loop, input

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to calculate the average of 4 numbers from the user I've gotten this far but i'm having issues in the input stage. I wanted to use a for loop to iterate for every number printing "Enter number one:" > user puts 2, its accumulates... Then is asks for the next one "Enter number two" adds to sum and so on until all for numbers have been added. However instead of taking each number at a time. The output for this program is:

number 1number 2number 3number 4:

Question: Why isn't it stopping at each iteration to allow the user to input a number?

```
namespace Hello
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double sum;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                Console.Write("Enter number {0}:", i);
                sum = +Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());



        }

    

    }

}
```

Comment: Your issue is what is answered below carina, by not using the curly braces you are only executing the line Console.Write, instead of the console.Write and the readline. So the flow of your code goes like For 1 to 4 print Enter number: 1.. 2..3..4. And then awaits for an input

Comment: You need brackets {} on the `for` loop as noted already. The code is only executing `Console.Write("Enter number {0}:", i);` 4 times. Then it executes `sum = +Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());` once. Then after the last line is read, the code exits. You need to add `Console.ReadLine()` or `ReadKey` before the code exits, otherwise you will never see the average the code is supposed to output, which appears to be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
double sum;

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    Console.Write("Enter number {0}:", i);
    sum += Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

You forgot to enclose your for loop in curly braces.